# Request Screen Share Within iframe

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have built a Chrome Extension which successfully implements screen sharing with WebRTC, however there is a requirement for the site which uses the extension to function within an iframe.

Is it possible to achieve this? An example of my code is below - the 'unknown' case is always executing when within an iframe.

```
function getUserScreen(sources, extensionId) {
    const request = {
            type: 'getUserScreen',
            sources: sources
    };
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extensionId, request, response => {
            switch (response && response.type) {
                case 'success':
                    log('success!');
                    resolve(response.streamId);
                    break;
                case 'error':
                    log('error!');
                    reject(new Error(error.message));
                    break;
                default:
                    log('unknown!');
                    reject(new Error('Unknown response'));
                    break;
            }
        });
    }).then(streamId => {
        return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video: {
                mandatory: {
                    chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
                    chromeMediaSourceId: streamId,
                    maxWidth: window.screen.width,
                    maxHeight: window.screen.height                         
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the `message` event. With 'message' event, an IFrame can use to communicate with the webpage, and therefore it can also talk to any content script that an extension might execute on that webpage; This approach is recommended by google as seen here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#host-page-communication

From the iframe, it would look something like this:

```
var msg = { type: "CUSTOM_FROM_IFRAME", data: "Say hi." };
parent.postMessage(msg, "*");

window.addEventListener("message", ev=>{
  if(ev.type == "CUSTOM_FROM_CONTENTSCRIPT") console.log("can proceed");
});
```

The content script:

```
window.addEventListener("message", ev=>
{
  if(ev.type == "CUSTOM_FROM_IFRAME")
     chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: ev.type, data: ev.data}, response => { 
     myIFrame_element.contentWindow.postMessage({type: "CUSTOM_FROM_CONTENTSCRIPT", data: response.data}, "*"); }); 
});
```

And from the background page you execute the content script code:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(mypgage_tab_id, {src: contentscript.js});
```